# Convert Avro Byte to String in Java

Tags: java, avro

I am reading in an Avro File with an input field that contains bytes ({"name":"report_id","type":"bytes"}) , while the rest is of type String.

I have problems converting the bytes fields to String. While I have tried several solutions yet, none of them successfully converted the ByteArray to an 'human readable' String.

My code is as follows:

```
DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>();

DataFileReader<GenericRecord> fileReader =
        new DataFileReader<>(new File(path), reader);
System.out.println(fileReader.getSchema().toString());

while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
    GenericRecord record = fileReader.next();
    ByteBuffer report_id = (ByteBuffer) record.get("report_id"); // This needs to be converted from bytes to String
    String converted_report_id = new String(report_id.array());
    System.out.println(converted_report_id);
    String converted_report_id_2 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(report_id).toString();
    System.out.println(converted_report_id_2);


}
```

The output is still:

```
G����HI�Ȅ�/9�
G����HI����/9�
```

My guess is, that the Charset might be wrong. But how do i get to know this ?

Comment: How were the bytes populated? (If they were intended to be a string, I'd expect the schema to say that rather than bytes...)

Comment: How do you know the bytes are UTF8, compared to say, UTF16 or other charset? The only way that you could know this is by talking to the person that made the file or try using a hex viewer application to inspect it

Comment: I have no infomation regarding the used charset nor can I talk to any knowledgeable person. My best try will be trying out different charset and evaluating the results